# How to click on suggestions in SearchView?

Tags: java, android

I have SearchView which loads suggestions when I write any word,
How to click suggestions to open new activity which differs according to the suggestion?

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setVoiceSearch(false);
    searchView.setCursorDrawable(R.drawable.custom_cursor);
    searchView.setEllipsize(true);
    searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Do some magic
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in `onQueryTextSubmit` do what you want:

```
  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
           if(query.isEquals("test"){
               Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
        }
            return false;
       }
```

Comment: thanks for reply
the searchview is in main activity but the items i want to search for them in another activities (loaded from database) which when i click open another activity show data differ according to item 

now, i want to click suggestions to open its last activity and i can't apply this idea